# Write data in file using python

Tags: python

I'm working on a python project and I want to write some data in a file text.txt but I have this error : `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'data' referenced before assignment`
This is my code :

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['POST','GET'])
def createapp():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.json
        print(data)
        
    with open('text.txt', 'a') as file:
        file.write(data)


if __name__ =='__main__':
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `data` to empty string before the condition. Otherwise it's undefined if the condition is false

```
data=''
if request.method == 'POST':
    data = request.json
    print(data)
    
with open('text.txt', 'a') as file:
    file.write(data)
```

Comment: Actually you will raise a `TypeError` here, because you must write a string to file. `data = ''` will fix it

Comment: thank you but the data is null I want to write in my file the data = request.json

Comment: You can write into the file within the `if` block. In that case, you don't need to declare `data` beforehand.

Comment: If I write it inside the if block it didn't show in the text.txt

Comment: So you are saying `data` is printed on terminal but not written into the `text.txt` file? Check what's printed on terminal.

Comment: Can you please start a private discussion so I can explain more my problem?

Comment: Sure! Where do you want to discuss? Possibly email?

Answer (score 3):

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    data = request.json
    print(data)
    
with open('text.txt', 'a') as file:
    file.write(data)
```

And what if `request.method != 'POST'`? You won't have defined `data`.

---

If you want to add something new (maybe a `0` or a `[]`) when `data` is null, you may want to add this before the `if` statement:

```
data = ''
```

Comment: I'm new to python I just want to add those data in the file text.txt

Comment: Small correction - `data = ''`, otherwise `TypeError` will be raised